# JAVA - numero capicua, primo y elevado al cuadrado, todo en uno

Tags: java, netbeans

estoy trabajando en una tarea donde el problema es el siguiente:
Ingresar un numero, el programa analizara el numero ingresado y nos indicara si es capicua o no, si es primo o no e imprimira en pantalla el resultado. Aunado a esto el numero lo elevara al cuadrado y lo imprimira tambien con los resultadoos anteriores.

```
package tarea;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class tarea{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numero;
        int numeroinvertido;
        String cadena, cadinv = "";

        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Ingresa un número:");
        numero = leer.nextInt();

        cadena = numero + "";

        for (int i = 0; i < cadena.lenght(); i++) {
            cadinv = cadena.charAt(i) + cadinv;
            {
                numeroinvertido = Integer.parseInt(cadinv);
                if (numero == numeroinvertido) {
                    System.out.println("El número "+numero+" es capicua!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("El número "+numero+" no es capicua!");
                }
                    System.out.println("El número "+numero+" es primo!");
                }
           

            }

            // double cuadrado = Math.pow(numero, 2);
            //System.out.println("El resultado elevado al cuadrado es " + cuadrado);
        }
    }
```

Ya encontre como poder elevar el numero, aunque no se como integrarlo, tampoco logro solucionar que  aparte de imprimir si es capicua o no, en la siguiente linea me muestre si es primo o no.

Algun consejo? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi recomendación es separar cada operación, es decir en un método verificar si es o no capicua, en otro verifica si es primo o no.

Te dejo el código.

```
   package tarea;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tarea {
    
    
    //estas constantes se usan en la salida, en el sistem out print, se usan para no estar escribiendo lo mismo en cada linea
    public static final String PRIMO=" Primo";
    public static final String CAPICUA=" Capicua";
    public static final String DESCRIPCION=" es un número";
    public static final String NEGATIVO=" no";
    
    /**
     * Metodo que retorna un boolean si es o no copicua
     * 
     * **/
    public static boolean esCapicua(int numero) {       
        int faltante=numero;
        int numeroInvertido=0;
        int restante=0;
        
        while(faltante!=0) {
            restante=faltante%10;
            numeroInvertido=numeroInvertido*10+restante;
            faltante=faltante/10;       
        }
        
        if(numeroInvertido==numero){                
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Metodo que retorna un boolean si es o no primo
     * 
     * **/  
    public static boolean esPrimo(int numero) {
          // El 0, 1 y 4 no son primos
          if (numero == 0 || numero == 1 || numero == 4) {
            return false;
          }
         
          for (int x = 2; x < numero / 2; x++) {
            // Si es divisible por cualquiera de estos números, no es primo
            if (numero % x == 0)
              return false;
          }
          // Si no se pudo dividir por ninguno de los de arriba, sí es primo
          return true;
    }
    
    
    
    public static void main(String args []) {
        int numero=0;
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingresa un número:");
        
        numero = leer.nextInt();
        
        if(esCapicua(numero)) {
            System.out.println(numero+DESCRIPCION+CAPICUA);
        }else {
            System.out.println(numero+NEGATIVO+DESCRIPCION+CAPICUA);

        }   
        if(esPrimo(numero)) {
            System.out.println(numero+DESCRIPCION+PRIMO);   
        }else {
            System.out.println(numero+NEGATIVO+DESCRIPCION+PRIMO);  
            
        }
        
        double cuadrado = Math.pow(numero, 2);
        System.out.println("El resultado elevado al cuadrado es " + cuadrado);
    }

}
```

Comment: Si algún día necesitas de guía no dudes en escribirme ing_omarhdez@hotmail.com

Comment: muchisimas gracias Omar, deja pruebo tus recomendaciones. Yo creo si te tomare la palabra luego para pedir de tu consejo :)